# Problema Sentencia Linq con viewmodel adentro de un select que puede ser null

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, linq, datatable

Espero me puedan ayudar con una duda que no he podido resolver.

Soy muy nuevo en C# y en MVC con asp.net , y bueno mi problema es que yo estoy haciendo una sentencia LINQ con dos viewmodels con dos niveles de select, el problema es que mi segundo viewmodel que es LogViewModel solo trae los que tienen el estados en el documento de recibido, el problema es que pueden existir ReceivedLogs = Null, ya que no puede haber ningun log con ese estatus recibido, quisiera ver si hay una forma de que si el reeivedlog = null exista alguna forma de yo llenarlo por default poniendole al Nameapprover = N/A, ya que a la hora de imprimirlo en un grid algunas columnas salen vacias porque no existe Nameapprover, y necesito que no salgan asi si no por defecto el N/A que comente, esta sentencia Linq la regreso como un JSON para que se imprima por el plug-in de datatable JS Server Side

A continuación les dejo mi sentencia LINQ

```
  var result = db.document.Select(d => new DocumentViewModel
  {
   DocumentId = d.DocumentId,
   Name = w.name
   ReceivedLogs = d.Logs
  .Where(l => l.Status == Status.Received)
  .Select(l => new LogViewModel
  {
     CurrentApprover = l.User,
     NameApprover = l.User.FullName
  }).FirstOrDefault()
  }).ToList();
```

Comment: Ese tipo de validación deberías de hacerla en la vista, ya que por lo que veo la propiedad ReceivedLogs  es un objeto de tipo LogViewModel por lo que no podrías asignarle un valor de tipo string "N/A", Ha no ser que generes un objeto anónimo.

Comment: Entiendo que debe ser por vista a y así lo tenía antes, pero estoy cargando lso datos del lado del servidor, no se reciben los datos de la misma forma

Comment: Si comprendo, entonces has un objeto de anónimo, así pueden hacer la validación dentro de tu select y según como la condición muestras tu objeto LogViewMdel o un string con "N/A"

Comment: Si recibes `NameApprover = l.User.FullName` null, puedes usar un operador `??` , de esta manera `NameApprover = l.User.FullName ?? "N/A"`

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar un comparador de nulos, en específico el operador `??`. quedaría así:

```
ReceivedLogs = d.Logs??"N/A";
```

Esto, lo que hace es que, si tiene `d.Logs` tiene un valor, lo respeta y lo mantiene. si no tiene, le pone por default "N/A", o el valor que quieras designar en tu `string`.

Espero la respuesta te sirva. ¡Saludos!

Comment: Hola el problema que con eso que me pones no se puede ya que me da un problema, recievedlogs es un tipo objeto no es un tipo string. Si pongo eso me va a dar error

Comment: entonces, qué dato quieres que tenga por default?

Answer (score 0):

La cuestión es que la propiedad ReceivedLogs es un objeto de tipo LogViewModel por lo que no puedes asignarle un string, te recomiendo que returnos un objeto anónimo de esta manera puedes realizar esa validación:

```
var result = db.document.Select(d => new
  {
   DocumentId = d.DocumentId,
   Name = w.name
   ReceivedLogs = d.Logs
  .Where(l => l.Status == Status.Received)
  .Select(l => new LogViewModel
  {
     CurrentApprover = l.User,
     NameApprover = l.User.FullName
  }).FirstOrDefault() ?? "N/A"
  }).ToList();
```

Comment: Me parece q estas haciendo lo contrario a lo q dices

Comment: No. Considero que esta seria una forma viable, deberías de probarlo y decirme si te funciona.

Comment: Tu la probaste?